# Equivalent of Xcode target output in Android Studio

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

Xcode offers two outputs to check, debugger output and target output (also all output which displays both).

I've an an app both developed in Xcode and in Android Studio, but I cannot find any way to display the same messages that appear in Xcode when we get response from a certain Bluetooth device.

It's possible that these messages aren't sent on Android version, but honestly I find it unlikely, likely the problem is that I'm not able to find the equivalent of that target output for Android Studio (I already checked in logcat and the messages that appear in XCode don't appear there).

Which would be the equivalent in Android Studio to that target output console?

Answer (score 1):

For android have a equivalent system based on gradle, 
build variants or gradle flavors,

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
    ...
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }

    /**
     * The `initWith` property allows you to copy configurations from other build types,
     * then configure only the settings you want to change. This one copies the debug build
     * type, and then changes the manifest placeholder and application ID.
     */
    staging {
        initWith debug
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"internal.example.com"]
        applicationIdSuffix ".debugStaging"
    }
}
```

}

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Answer (score 1):

Logcat is the right place.
You can use the `Log` class to output messages. `Log.d(String, String)` is for debugging message. You can use `Log.e`, `Log.v`and so on to log messages with various verbosity levels.

In order to see your log messages in logcat, make sure that you select the correct device (2. in the screenshot). To filter out unwanted messages you should select your application (also "2.") and set the filter to "Show only selected application" (3.).

[image: Example for logging messages in Android Studio with kotlin]